# Amcharts Serial - load multiple ajax data as dataprovider

Tags: javascript, ajax, amcharts

I am trying to create a serial graph with multiple ajax loaded data. So far I haven't seen anyone doing this but I was able to use an example online of something similar. The problem with the result is that it takes so long to load and all the data are clustered together. Is there a way to load each data returned from each ajax to a particular graph (Only status and counter are the only data returned)?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var chartDataResults = new Array();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "../NewProjectEdit.aspx/bronxBind",
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      generateChartData(data.d);
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "../NewProjectEdit.aspx/brooklynBind",
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      generateChartData(data.d);
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "../NewProjectEdit.aspx/manhattanBind",
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      generateChartData(data.d);
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "../NewProjectEdit.aspx/queensBind",
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      generateChartData(data.d);
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "../NewProjectEdit.aspx/statenIslandBind",
    data: '{}',
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      generateChartData(data.d);
    }
  });


  function generateChartData(dataValues) {
    for (var i = dataValues.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {

      console.log(dataValues[1]);
      var chartItems = dataValues[i];
      var chartStatus = chartItems.status
      var chartCounter = chartItems.counter

      chartDataResults.push({
        status: chartStatus,
        counter: chartCounter
      });

      var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
        "type": "serial",
        "theme": "light",
        "depth3D": 20,
        "angle": 30,
        "legend": {
          "horizontalGap": 10,
          "useGraphSettings": true,
          "markerSize": 10
        },
        "valueAxes": [{
          "stackType": "regular",
          "axisAlpha": 0,
          "gridAlpha": 0
        }],
        "dataProvider": chartDataResults,
        "graphs": [{
          "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
          "fillAlphas": 0.8,
          "labelText": "[[value]]",
          "lineAlpha": 0.3,
          "title": "Bronx",
          "type": "column",
          "color": "#000000",
          "valueField": "counter"
        }, {
          "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
          "fillAlphas": 0.8,
          "labelText": "[[value]]",
          "lineAlpha": 0.3,
          "title": "Brooklyn",
          "type": "column",
          "color": "#000000",
          "valueField": "counter"
        }, {
          "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
          "fillAlphas": 0.8,
          "labelText": "[[value]]",
          "lineAlpha": 0.3,
          "title": "Manhattan",
          "type": "column",
          "color": "#000000",
          "valueField": "counter"
        }, {
          "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
          "fillAlphas": 0.8,
          "labelText": "[[value]]",
          "lineAlpha": 0.3,
          "title": "Queens",
          "type": "column",
          "color": "#000000",
          "valueField": "counter"
        }, {
          "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
          "fillAlphas": 0.8,
          "labelText": "[[value]]",
          "lineAlpha": 0.3,
          "title": "Staten Island",
          "type": "column",
          "color": "#000000",
          "valueField": "counter"
        }],
        "categoryField": "status",
        "categoryAxis": {
          "gridPosition": "start",
          "axisAlpha": 0,
          "gridAlpha": 0,
          "position": "left",
          "labelRotation": -45
        },
        "export": {
          "enabled": true
        }

      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.amcharts-export-menu-top-right {
  top: 10px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" background-color: #FFFFFF; " ></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your approach.

1) Don't use `async: false`. It's deprecated in modern browsers due to the poor user experience as each request will block the browser until resolved. You can take advantage of promises using jQuery's `$.when` and `.then` allowing you to wait for all of your AJAX requests to resolve before executing a callback to merge your data and create your chart.

```
$.when(
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "../NewProjectEdit.aspx/bronxBind",
    dataType: 'json'
  }),
  // each ajax request
).then(function(bronxData, brooklynData, manhattanData, queensData, statenIslandData) {
  var chartDataResults = mergeData(bronxData[0], brooklynData[0], manhattanData[0], statenIslandData[0]);
  //makeChart here.
});
```

2) Don't call `makeChart` multiple times. This causes performance issues as you're now creating multiple instances that are all fighting  for control within the same div. Use promises as indicated in point #1 to synchronize your calls and data before finally creating your chart.

3) Each graph's `valueField` must be unique, so you have to merge your data while creating separate valueFields for each borough, which will allow you to populate each graph individually. Here's a merge method I came up with based on your setup:

```
function mergeData(bronxData, brooklynData, manhattanData, queensData, statenIslandData) {
  var dataMap = {}; //object map used to group all data by category.
  var chartData = [];

  //collect all the data from each borough into the dataMap
  bronxData.forEach(function(data) {
    dataMap[data.status] = { 'bronxCounter': data.counter };
  });

  brooklynData.forEach(function(data) {
    if (!dataMap[data.status]) {
      dataMap[data.status] = {};
    }
    dataMap[data.status].brooklynCounter = data.counter
  });
  manhattanData.forEach(function(data) {
    if (!dataMap[data.status]) {
      dataMap[data.status] = {};
    }
    dataMap[data.status].manhattanCounter = data.counter
  });
  queensData.forEach(function(data) {
    if (!dataMap[data.status]) {
      dataMap[data.status] = {};
    }
    dataMap[data.status].queensCounter = data.counter
  });
  statenIslandData.forEach(function(data) {
    if (!dataMap[data.status]) {
      dataMap[data.status] = {};
    }
    dataMap[data.status].statenIslandCounter = data.counter
  });

  //convert dataMap into an array:
  Object.keys(dataMap).forEach(function(status) {
    dataMap[status].status = status; //assign the status categoryField
    chartData.push(dataMap[status]);  //add object to array
  });

  return chartData;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xnok80df/1/) demonstrating all of this. Note that it uses jsfiddle's echo endpoint to simulate AJAX requests, but the general idea is the same for your use case.